# What does the "-" mean in Xcode project navigator?

Tags: xcode, version-control

[image]

Using Xcode 11.

That little em dash is bothering me. I never see an "M" next to Storyboard anymore, no matter how many changes I make to it, and I worry that things might be missed when I commit.

What does it mean, and how can I get back to seeing a "--" in its place?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, the "-" indicates the git status for your storyboard, here is the diagram for your reference.

[image]

Source:- [From Sam's book](https://books.google.de/books?id=FS75BgAAQBAJ&pg=RA1-PA10&lpg=RA1-PA10&dq=the%20content%20of%20the%20folder%20has%20mixed%20status&source=bl&ots=SjFGFuF9Nf&sig=ACfU3U2LtDmIy1vJBFLzNClSsh_nBEbBzw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwim0pix4d_nAhXI2aQKHYODDiwQ6AEwAnoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=the%20content%20of%20the%20folder%20has%20mixed%20status&f=false)

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yeah, I saw that post, but I’m still confused because the storyboard is a file, not a folder. What am I not getting?